# Syntax for assigning to a struct in a struct

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct Entity that is made up of Limbs and an enum, Limbs is also a struct with two items e.g.

```
typedef enum{ALIVE, DEAD} state;

typedef struct Limb{
    int is_connected;
    int is_wounded;
} Limb;

typedef struct Entity{
    Limb limb_1;
    Limb limb_2;
    state is_alive;
} Entity;
```

Now lets say I have a function that's designed to assign entity particular values, what is the proper syntax to use here? My current guess is this:

```
void assign_entity(Entity *entity){
    *entity = {
        .limb_1 = { 1, 0 },
        .limb_2 = { 1, 0 },
        .is_alive = ALIVE
    };
}
```

But I get an error (expected expression) when I use this syntax, what am I doing wrong here? What is the proper syntax for assigning to a struct inside a struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a [compound literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) but omitting the proper syntax.

It should be:

```
void assign_entity(Entity *entity){
    *entity = ((Entity) { 
        .limb_1 = { 1, 0 },
        .limb_2 = { 1, 0 },
        .is_alive = ALIVE
    });
}
```

Note that this requires C99 (or a suitably extended compiler, of course).

Comment: The `( )` should be outside the `{ }`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp D'oh! Yes, true. Too small font when I read the GNU page. :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably too verbose for someone the code below:

```
void assign_entity(Entity *entity)
{
    entity->limp_1.is_connected = 1;
    entity->limp_1.is_wounded= 0;
    entity->limp_2.is_connected = 1;
    entity->limp_2.is_wounded= 0;
    entity->is_alive = ALIVE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Designated initializer syntax can only be used in an initialization.

One way to do what you want would be:

```
Entity const new = {
    .limb_1 = { 1, 0 },
    .limb_2 = { 1, 0 },
    .is_alive = ALIVE
};

*entity = new;
```

Comment: So basically instead of entity = { .x =  foobar, .y = foobar } I'd have to do entity.x = foobar; entity.y = foobar; ?

Comment: @V-X what's wrong with it? we're making a new entity

Comment: You're making a new entity. The same way you can call it `a` or `making` or even `we` or `are`. You can call that also as `this` or `that`. I just don't like the constant name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already allocated memory at the address pointed to by `entity` and all you're trying to do is "assign particular values", then you would do it as follows:

```
void assign_entity(Entity *entity)
{
    entity->limb_1 = ( 1, 0 );
    entity->limb_2 = ( 1, 0 );
    entity->is_alive = ALIVE;
}
```

Or, if you want to roll it all up into one line:

```
void assign_entity(Entity *entity)
{
    *entity = ((1, 0), (1, 0), ALIVE);
}
```